# Microsoft keyboard - can I have FLock always "on"?

Tags: keyboard

I like Microsoft Natural 4000 keyboard but I hate "FLOCK" key. It seems sometimes I push it by accident and then F1-F12 keys stop working.

For Example in Windows Explorer I try to rename file pressing "F2" but instead of that I involve "Undo" action. So instead of renaming files I have created previously just disappear! It's very inconvenient! I never use "Function keys" so can I somehow just have FLOCK enabled?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/618467/microsoft-keyboard-can-i-have-flock-always-on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can disable the key, however, you could just replace the function on the key with a macro like so.

1. Open [Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center).
2. Select **Macro** as the command and click the macro name to define a new macro:

   [image]
3. Click **Create a new Macro**.
4. Create a macro named **F2** and insert a <kbd>F2</kbd> key press into the editor:

   [image]
5. Make sure the F2 macro is selected for the key.

Comment: and repeat that for every key?

Comment: @javapowered: Right

Comment: thank you for this answer.  I've already lost data to hitting f2 and getting an undo command after file-move that couldn't be undone correctly.  Now I don't have to worry about this happening again.

Answer (score 2):

At this [site](http://jtsang.mvps.org/usb_intellitype.html), you can find a modified commands.xml file. 
To use this modified file, place it in the directory that Intellitype Pro is installed to (typically, this would be `C:\Program Files\Microsoft IntelliType Pro`).

If you wish to revert the changes, is included the original commands.xml file (just rename it from commands.original.xml to commands.xml).

> Intellitype Pro is feature added software that allows a user to reprogram various keys on 
>   their Microsoft keyboard.

See this [article](http://blackbeltreview.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/logitech-elite-keyboard-default-f-lock-behavior/) that explains how to do this by registry editor.

Comment: this example is very old and likely is not fully compatible with the latest version of keyboard driver, at least it seems so from the diff of provided file and one from my filesystem.

Comment: @javapowered It should work.  If you're really concerned, just backup the current `commands.xml`, try out Jason Tsangs, and if that doesn't work, restore the original.